# A form for each entity displayed on page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

my problem is quite simple but i can't find any help about it...
I have to little entities, with a OneToOne relationship

**Task**
id
name
user_id (FK)

**User**
id
name

On my page, I display all the tasks existing on the 'Task' table (with a classic findAll() function), and I would like to display next to each task, a short form to let the user fill his name and save it.

Something like that :

```
Task #1 -- [input text for the username] [submit button]
Task #2 -- [input text for the username] [submit button]
Task #3 -- [input text for the username] [submit button]
Task #4 -- [input text for the username] [submit button]
...
```

Is this possible with Symfony2 and how ? Using Entity collections ?

Thanks.
Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a form view for each object , then store it in a variable to be displayed in twig .

```
   // in your php
   $forms = array();

   for ( $tasks as $task )
   {
      $form = $this->createForm( new formType() , $task );

      $forms[] = $form->createView();
   }

   return $this->render ( "path.to.html.twig", array ( "forms" => $forms ) );


   // in your twig
```

define a macro http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

```
{% macro drawForms(forms) %}
    {% for form in forms %}
          {{ form_errors(form) }}
          {{ form_start(form) }}

          <button type="submit">Submit / Save </button>
          {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

 // call of your macro in your html . Import here state that our macro is in the same twig. otherwise you have to define in which twig the macro is located
 {% import _self as macro %}
 {{ forms.drawForms( forms ) }}
```

The macro function is not mandatory here: You can directly call you loop in your twig , but it's nice way to ordering your code, specially when you want to make some recursive code in twig :)